# NavigationStart not getting called for angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to track url changes using navigationStart event of angular. I am writing a feature module and this url tracking needs to be done in a service and not a component. I don't even have a component. In this url tracking handler, I also want to find out the hash fragment of url. I tried below code but navigationStart never gets fired. If I have to map it to angularjs then this is how we used to do it.

**angularjs code**

```
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', locationChangeHandler);

  var locationChangeHandler = function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
}
```

**angular Code**

```
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(  private router: Router , private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
      console.log("My hash fragment is here => ", fragment)
    })

    this.router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof   NavigationStart)
      .pairwise()
      .subscribe((e) => {
        console.log("inside navigation start");
        console.log(e) })



    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {

   // This didn't work
   //if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
     //   console.log("navigation started");
     // }

      else if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log("navigation ended");
      }


      else if(event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
        console.log("navigation cancelled");
      }

      else if(event instanceof NavigationError) {
        console.log("navigation errored");
      }


      else if(event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        console.log("navigation routes recognized");
      }

    })


  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are building a canActivate guard, which is only run *after* the navigation has started. That is why are you not seeing the Navigation start.

You can see the order of the routing events here: https://angular.io/api/router/Event

Notice that the `GuardsCheckStart` is when your `canActivate` guard is executed, which is *after* the navigation start.

I normally put this type of code in my app component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Event, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationError, NavigationCancel } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'mh-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    loading: boolean = true;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
            this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent);
        });
    }

    checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event): void {
        if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.loading = true;
        }

        if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
            routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
            routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
            this.loading = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Deboarh - I am writing a feature module for authentication and I don't even have a component. Is there a way I can get a call back in my feature module for url changes. This was possible in angularjs so there should be some way in angular as well.

Comment: I don't understand enough about what you are trying to do to suggest. I have not seen a feature module built with no components.

Comment: It's an oauth library and can be use to authenticate the route/navigation. I need to parse the url to get the access_token. I don't see how can I use a component.

Comment: OK, then a route guard may make sense ... but you won't be able to catch the route start event. I am unclear why you need to?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm going in another direction here, I'm making it a new answer.

Here is what one of my `CanActivate` guards looks like (see below). Notice that it has a `canActivate` method that provides the route information and route state information. You should be able to use that method to pull off any part of the URL that you need.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router,
         CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export  class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
                private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.checkLoggedIn(state.url);
    }

    checkLoggedIn(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Retain the attempted URL for redirection
        this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Deborah! But canActivate doesn't get called for all url changes. It gets called only for route changes. One route change can lead to multiple times url changes.For example, on my route change, I am calling a service and the service sends the access_token in the url. I want to get a call back as soon as I see a change in the url.

Comment: This is a related issue if it helps and it's still not working for me https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13244

Comment: OK, you had not mentioned query parameters in anything above. BUT ... if you read to the bottom of the link you posted ... they provided a fix: https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers